# Dell vostro boots from usb live but not with windows

Tags: windows-10, bluescreenview

My windows Dell vostro 14 5459 stooped booting with the installed win10, I tried to boot it with bootable USB Ubuntu it worked I found my files and backed them up. But when trying to format it, I couldn't get in to the BIOS simply show blue screen or Recovery options which won' work.
The blue screen errors change now and then, to mention some.

- irql not less or not equal
- Memory management error
- System pte misuse...

Comment: You should always be able to access the firmware (UEFI in this case, not really BIOS) regardless of the state of the installed OS but if you can't find out how you may try the option to boot to UEFI settings in the Grub menu of your USB Ubuntu media.

Answer (score 1):

You have everything backed up (per your post).

Use the Microsoft Media Creation link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Use the section that says "Make a USB for a different PC", make a bootable USB Key.

Now do a new install of Windows 10.

There might be a hardware error, but it does not seem so from your post.

Comment: But I can't go in to the bios or boot sequence, I was able to get in to safe mode option when I plugged a USB Keyboard

Comment: Try running Setup on the Windows 10 USB Key when you are in Safe Mode.

Answer (score 0):

This might resolve your problem -

1. Shut your computer down.
2. Press the power/start button and restart your computer.
3. *Immediately* start tapping the F12 key.
4. When the screen comes up, select OS Recovery.
5. OS Recovery will take a few seconds to load.  View the tutorial to become familiar with the process and options that will be used.  Begin, and follow the process.
6. You can recursively use OS Recovery for a second or third time (more if necessary) to repair issues that were not corrected on the current/previous recovery pass.
7. When you get a satisfactory, functional, *or at least minimally useable* repaired operating system, go into Windows Update and update your current version to the latest version.  This will completely correct issues with your repaired operating system and essentially give you a new, current version of the Windows 10 operating system.
8. Replace your files as necessary.  As noted, you had already backed up your files.
9. Use the Dell Update feature (look in your Start listing, go to the Dell folder and left click on the folder, select Dell Update) and update your drivers and BIOS as necessary.  A suggestion is to update your drivers.  You also have the option to allow Dell to scan your system and suggest updates when they are noticed as necessary. This process should be completed from time to time as further fortification of your system.

If you are able to complete this process, your laptop should be functional without problems.

Comment: I tried to install windows with windows media creation but it wan't able to boot form the usb, however I have been able to boot it using ubuntu OS. Also I can't seem to get into F12 or F2 BIOS. Simply jumps to recovery window or Bluescreen window. I was able to get to safe mode window using F8 when I plugged in USB keyboard but even safe mode wan't helpful in anyway. Also I tested the memory using Ubuntu and it showed 0MB. Am not sure if it's RAM failure or board failure.